# Round tabs with Ionic

Tags: html, ionic-framework, bootstrap-4, angular2-template

I used this code to navigate between the pages:

```
 <super-tabs tabsPlacement="top" toolbarBackground="3D9BDD" toolbarColor="dark" indicatorColor="light"
(tabSelect)="onTabSelect($event)">
<super-tab *ngFor="let page of pages" [root]="page.pageName" [icon]="page.icon" [id]="page.id"></super-tab>
```

But now I need to change the icon to round images of PNGs,
How can I do it with Ionic/html/Bootstrap?

Thanks!